# Product url give 404 error to crawling even product is enabled and visibility set to catalog search.

Tags: magento-1.9

Some of the products url gives 404 error to crawl url, if that product is enabled and visibility set to catalog, search. Also i found there is some product randomly giving 404 error to crawl.

I have checked products in admin and is enabled with stock set. I checked the URL rewrite section but couldn't find anything. Also, tried reindexing everything, but couldn't resolve the issue. Even flushed the cache still nothing.

If i hit the particular product url, its working properly.

Comment: you can check your core_url_rewrite table for those urls, maybe Magento save some urls there. I had a similar problem before, solved it by removing those lines from core_url_rewrite table.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue in past at that time i have created latest sitemap and updated.